# Ffmpeg flutter image to video

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working on Flutter app and I have feature to convert an image to a video with audio so I'm using:

> ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.3

for this task. But when I use this command:

```
'-loop 1 -i $imagePath -c:v libx264 -t $videoDuration -pix_fmt yuv420p $outputVideoPath'
```

I have an error say that:

> libx264 Unknown codec

When I remove it, the video has successfully output a file but not working.

Any idea about the right way to solve this issue?

Comment: Use this package: `packages/flutter_ffmpeg_https-gpl` instead: https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg/issues/9